# Working with Grid using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a `GridControl` which I populate using a `BackgroundWorker`. Then I'm using another `BackgroundWorker` to perform some calculations on the dataset which is the datasource of the `GridControl`. As I'm trying to do this a cross thread operation on the `GridControl` error is thrown. I'm unable to understand that despite not performaing any operation on the gridcontrol itself how the error is generating. (I'm using DevExpress, but that should not change the concept).

Also is there any way I can use one `BackgroundWorker` to do different work, i.e. make this code more efficient.

Here is my code:-

```
public partial class MainForm : XtraForm
    {
        private BackgroundWorker loadworker = new BackgroundWorker();
        private BackgroundWorker calcworker = new BackgroundWorker();
        private AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private Database _db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("ConnString");
        private DataSet ds;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            loadworker.DoWork += loadworker_DoWork;
            loadworker.RunWorkerCompleted += loadworker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            loadworker.ProgressChanged += loadworker_ProgressChanged;
            loadworker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            calcworker.DoWork += calcworker_DoWork;
            calcworker.RunWorkerCompleted += calcworker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            calcworker.ProgressChanged += calcworker_ProgressChanged;
            calcworker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

        private void calcworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int _cnt = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                dr["GROSS"] = (decimal)dr["BASIC"] + (decimal)dr["HRA"] + (decimal)dr["DA"];
                _cnt += 1;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= _cnt; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                calcworker.ReportProgress((100 * i) / _cnt);
            }
        }

        private void calcworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetState(true);
            this.MainInit();
        }

        private void calcworker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.pgb_DataProgress.Position = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }


        private void loadworker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.pgb_DataProgress.Position = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void loadworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DbCommand _cmd = _db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT Z.EMP_CODE,Z.BASIC,Z.DA,Z.HRA,CAST(0 AS DECIMAL) GROSS FROM Z000000001 Z");
                DataSet _data = _db.ExecuteDataSet(_cmd);

                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    loadworker.ReportProgress((100 * i) / 10);
                }

                e.Result = _data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        private void loadworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ds = (DataSet)e.Result;
            this.gridControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            this.SetState(true);
            this.MainInit();
        }

        private void btn_FetchData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.gridControl1.DataSource = null;
            this.SetState(false);
            loadworker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void SetState(bool _state)
        {
            this.btn_Calculate.Enabled = _state;
            this.btn_ClearGrid.Enabled = _state;
            this.btn_FetchData.Enabled = _state;
        }

        private void MainInit()
        {
            this.pgb_DataProgress.Position = 0;
        }

        private void btn_ClearGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.gridControl1.DataSource = null;
        }

        private void btn_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.gridControl1.DataSource == null)
            {
                DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("Data Not loaded", "Message");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                this.SetState(false);
                calcworker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You change the DataRow from within `calcworker_DoWork`. Through change-notification your grid will be informed and this is done from the same thread as the row-change is done. That's why the code throws an exception. A possibility would be to set the Row in loadworker_ProgressChanged. You can transfer the data through the UserState of the ReportProgress-method.

Comment: @HCL: So what should be the approach. Shall I fist set the GridControl datasource to be null then perform the calculations and then again set the datasource. This method is working but is this a good way or do you suggest otherwise.

Comment: The way you say is the fastest way because no cross-thread communication takes place. However the User-Experience may be not so good if it is a long-term operation. A possibility is to use Control.Invoke as VinayC wrote or to show a progressbar or you set the data in the row through in the ProgressChanged-event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you cannot access controls on a thread other than UI thread on which they are created. So any control method/property call has to be marshall on the UI thread using [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method.

For example, in your case `loadworker_RunWorkerCompleted` event handler will be invoked on a worker thread and accessing control property will throw an error. You need to modify event handler as

```
    private void loadworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Action a = () => {
          this.ds = (DataSet)e.Result;
          this.gridControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
          this.SetState(true);
          this.MainInit();
        };
        this.gridControl1.Invoke(a);
    }
```

Comment: @VinayC: What is the best way to tackle this problem.

Comment: @Soham, edited to show how to use invoke when doing cross thread operation. You have to use such code at every method accessing controls that may get invoked on different thread.

Comment: -1, This is wrong!  The Completed event is executed on the main GUI Thread so this Invoke stuff is completely unneeded. And certainly not solving the problem.

Comment: @VinayC: Works like a charm.. Can you explain the System.Action? Is it lambda function?

Comment: @Soham, this worked? You must have changed something else too.

Comment: @Soham - System.Action is a helper delegate type and I have created its instance using a lambda expression. Control.Invoke will not accept lambda (as actual delegate type cannot be inferred).

Comment: @Henk, what you are saying is right only if Soham had created BackgroundWorker on form design surface - only is such case, those worker would know about parent GUI context to marshal completed event to GUI thread. But in Soham's case, he is creating workers in code and they are not associated with the form anyway hence the need for marshalling.

Comment: @VinayC: Can I write a Action delegate without using lambda expression? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @VinayC: Incorrect, the Bgw will find the right thread using its ExecutionContext. It is easy to try out. Completed and ProcessChanged always happen on the GUI thread

Comment: @Henk: I wrote it inside the DoWork event. It worked. But how would I make it work in .NET 2.0. I think this is not available in .NET 2.0 is it?

Comment: @Soham, you can use Anonymous Methods syntax.In .NET 2.0, you have to declare some delegate such as public delegate void MyAction(); And then MyAction a = delegate() { ... };

Comment: @Henk - thanks for correcting. Checking from reflector, BackgroundWorker indeed adds logic for invoke while adding event handler. However, it still beats me that Soham's problem has been resolved because DoWork does not seem to be accessing any control.

Comment: @VinayC: I don't know whether DevExpress gridControl has been rigged to do so.

Answer (score 1):

After you attached the Table as DataSource it belongs to the GUI. Suppose your user alters/deletes a row while your Calc thread is running. All sorts of race conditions might happen.